# No exception of type Exception can be thrown, an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable

Tags: java, exception, throwable

I was seaching this problem in other questions but still didn't figure out 
what does exactly mean Throwable. Read a few articles about it (its superclas bla bla bla) but still don't know how to implement it. Forgot to mention i am new to java. Any advice would be gratefully accepted :D

Here is the Exception class:

```
class Exception {
private int pDen;
private int pMes;
private int kDen;
private int kMes;

public Exception(int pDen, int pMes, int kDen, int kMes) {
    super();
    this.pDen = pDen;
    this.pMes = pMes;
    this.kDen = kDen;
    this.kMes = kMes;
}
public void message()
{
    System.out.println("Isklucok");
}
public void promena()
{
    int tmpDen = 0;
    int tmpMes = 0;
    tmpDen = pDen;
    pDen = kDen;
    kDen = tmpDen;
    tmpMes = pMes;
    pMes = kMes;
    kMes = tmpMes;
}
```

}

And here is the code that i run in other class where shoud i catch my exception where is thrown.

```
try {
        if(pMes > kMes)
        {
            throw new Exception(pDen,pMes,kDen,kMes);
        }
        else if(pMes == kMes)
            if(pDen > kDen)
            {
                throw new Exception(pDen,pMes,kDen,kMes);
            }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.message();
        e.promena();
    }
```

Comment: Why create your own exception class instead of using eg IllegalArgumentException or IllegalStateException?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make your custom exception extends something from the `Throwable` hierarchy.

For example

```
// Exception here is java.lang.Exception, not the class from your example
public class MyException extends Exception {

    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 3):

> The class Exception and its subclasses are a form of Throwable
>   that indicates conditions that a reasonable application might want to
>   catch.

In most situations your exception would be one of them below:

- Arithmetic Exception
- ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException
- ClassNotFoundException
- IOException
- NoSuchMethodException ...

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems
>   that a reasonable application should not try to catch.

Both `Exception` and `Error` are subclasses of `Throwable`.

If you need to not only catch `Exceptions` but `Errors`, you should use `Throwable`. But:

> Most such errors are abnormal conditions. The ThreadDeath error,
>   though a "normal" condition, is also a subclass of Error because most
>   applications should not try to catch it.

If you want to catch such a thing like `ThreadDeath` error you would use Throwable. That might be a very rare situation.

In your example if you simply want to check the numbers, you can use something like this:

```
public static void check(int pDen, int pMes, int kDen, int kMes) {

    if (pMes > kMes) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Your message.....");
    } else if (pMes == kMes) {
        if (pDen > kDen) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Your message.....");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please ignore the answers suggesting you implement your own `Exception` class. Java has its own: `java.lang.Exception`. Just use that, and extend it if needed. Cases where it makes sense to have your own `Throwable`, but not extend from the standard `Exception` are very rare.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a custom `Exception` class containing the required `Constructors` as follows:

```
public class CustomException extends Exception {
    /* Optional: Include Serial UID */

    public CustomException(Throwable t) {
        super(t);
    }

    public CustomException(int pDen, int pMes, int kDen, int kMes) {
        /* Handle Info & Throw Exception */
    }

}
```

And then you can throw the exception as follows,

```
throw new CustomException(pDen,pMes,kDen,kMes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Points to avoid this common error while writing any Java program:

1. Make sure you are not importing any package for `Exception` class.
2. If you find any import for this remove it.
3. You can implement by extending Exception class.
4. Or by throwing an `Exception` from the method.
5. Use `throw` when creating a custom message to be thrown along with throws keyword on method.

Answer (score -1):

In your custom class extends Throwable. Its working

```
 class Exception extends Throwable {
      //your code
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this exception when I hadn't imported the Exception type into the class that was catching it